# How do you create an instance of a datatype with a record in SML?

Tags: record, sml, ml

For example if you were to have

```
datatype 'a DT =
   thingy of {field1: int, field2: int}
| Empty DT;
```

How would you be able to create "thingy" with its fields filled in, within a function? Assuming you have the values you want for each field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`- datatype 'a DT = thingy of {x: int, y: int} | Empty;
datatype 'a DT = Empty | thingy of {x:int, y:int}
- thingy {x = 5, y = 4};
val it = thingy {x=5,y=4} : 'a DT
- fun f x y = thingy {x = x, y = y};
val f = fn : int -> int -> 'a DT`

Comment: Why the polymorphic type `'a` if you don't used it? You can probably do away with it.

Comment: It's in his example.  It's possibly not useless.  It could be used as a phantom type, for example.